# Pack a .net standard 2.0 nuget package with local dll`s references and local nuget package

Tags: nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0, nuspec

I have a .net standard 2.0 class library project with the following setup:

- At the solution root folder (the .sln file location) I have a nuget package (Which also has
  other nuget dependencies) a co-worker wrote
  which I need to use. I configured this location as a package source and added the nuget package
  through package manager.
- At the solution root folder (the .sln file location) I also have 'dlls' folder in which i have
  a dll I added refence to manually (through refence manager)

**This is the class library with the dependencies**

[image]

I try pack at using VS 19 right clicking on the project and 'Pack' option. But only the class library dll is added

So I also tried packing it with `.nuspec` file to take all files from release folder

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>  

        ...
        ...
        <!-- Dependencies are automatically installed when the package is installed -->
       <dependencies> 
           <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0"></group>
         </dependencies> 
    </metadata>

    
    <files>
        <file src=".\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\*.*" target="lib\netstandard2.0" />
    </files>
</package>
```

And it does pack all dlls. But There I get an exception when running the application which used the generated nuget package.

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI) is not supported on this platform.'
```

I am testing it using `.net core 3.0` console app.

If I use the class library I try to pack by adding it as a project reference to the console app, it all works perfect.

What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT:***

As **@Lasse V. Karlsen** requested, I tried unpacking the nuget and add the dlls as references and did noticed some problem.

So, Again this is the class library with the nuget package my co-worker wrote. with the packages refernced by that package extended, Pay attention to `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData`

[image]

When add my nuget package to console app:

[image]

**But when I try to unpack the package and add the dlls refernces, I get an error on 3 of the dlls `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData` depends on.** Those which marked at the pictures.
I get this error when try to add them:

[image]

Comment: On which platform are you running your application?

Comment: Windows 10, Again: If I use the class library I try to pack by adding it as a project reference to the console app, it all works perfect.

Comment: So just so I understand it. If you add it as a nuget reference, it doesn't work, but if you add it as a direct dll reference, then it works? Can you try unzipping your nuget package and direct referencing the dll inside, just to rule out that the dll's are actually different?

Comment: You understand correct. I did noticed something weird after your suggestion. I edited the question

Comment: Does this provide any insight? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208262/net-standard-2-0-and-system-security-cryptography-protecteddata-protect - I'm just winging it now, I have no idea :)

Comment: Thank for the effort. I also saw that example. But the fact it works when using the class library as a reference in the console app makes me believe is more of an issue of configuration for packing the nuget rather then that exception. I think if i could pack the package with the local nuget package and the dll it will work fine